# How to get the values between particular date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the values between particular date and time. But each values - time, hour and minutes are there in separate fields.

Following is the table format i have,

```
Date        Hour    Min     values

1/1/2011    10      30      Test1
2/1/2011    8       10      Test2
3/1/2011    15      40      Test3
5/1/2011    11      10      Test5
10/1/2011   3       04      Test6
12/1/2011   5       00      Test6
```

Now i want to get the "values" between '3/1/2011 12.00' and '10/1/2011 11.10' using MYSQL SELECT query. If anyone knows pls help me

Comment: show us your try query..

Comment: You shouldn't store your datetime in such format

Comment: Store dates and times as a single entity.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(dateval,' ',hourval,':',minval,':00') as t 
 FROM ForgeRock 
 WHERE CAST(CONCAT(dateval,' ',hourval,':',minval,':00') as DATETIME) 
  between CAST('2006-01-21 17:10:00' as DATETIME) AND 
   CAST('2006-01-25 22:10:00' as DATETIME)
```

Because of concate() we need to use CAST to convert them as datetime.
SQL fiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a072/12

Comment: I need to include time also in where condition, then only i will get correct output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check @Suresh Kamrushi

Comment: Suppose my query is, `SELECT values FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT(`date`,' ',Hour,':',Min,':00') between '3/1/2011 12.00' and '10/1/2011 11.10'` then it is returning `3/1/2011 11.00` value too.. @Suresh Kamrushi

Comment: share your query

Comment: `SELECT values FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT(`date`,' ',Hour,':',Min,':00') between '2011/1/03 16.00' and '2011/1/10 11.10'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148032/discussion-between-kms-and-suresh-kamrushi).

Comment: @KMS This is such a terrible idea, there is really little point in discussing it further.

Comment: Incidentally, in this instance, casting is unnecessary. MySQL can evaluate the string as a string or as a date. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Updating @Suresh answer, as the default `date` format is 'Y-m-d'.

```
SELECT values
FROM table_name
WHERE `Date` between '2011-01-03' and '2011-10-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use alternate of Between..

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Date >= '2011-01-03' and Date < '2011-10-01'
```